# Display 6 (distinct) images from an array, don't show duplicates and reload every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 12 images in total. I want to display a maximum of 6 distinctive images at any one time - without showing duplicates. To do this I am using jQuery. I want the images to change/rotate every 5 seconds.

I can't seem to get this code to work. Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

```js
var imagesArray = [
  imgs / Scan1.jpeg ',
  '../imgs/Scan2.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan3.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan4.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan5.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan6.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan7.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan8.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan9.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan10.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan11.jpeg',
  '../imgs/Scan12.jepg',
];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;

function displayImage() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
  if (!usedImages[num]) {
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    usedImages[num] = true;
    usedImagesCount++;
    if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length) {
      usedImagesCount = 0;
      usedImages = {};
    }
  } else {
    setInterval(function() {
      $("#deluxe_img").attr("src", displayImage(););
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="premium_listing_container">
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
  <img src="function(displayImage())" id="deluxe_img" />
</div>
```

Comment: You also might wanna create those <img> tags dynamically instead of hard coding them. It will make it easier also for you to update the images and/or if you change your mind about the number 6 easier to maintain. - EDIT -> I would try play with the DOM and define a function that has reload interval of 5000 and add the <img> tags dynamically inside your "premium_listing_container"

Comment: You have a lot going on here.

First, HTML element IDs must be unique for every element. In other words, 6 elements with the id `deluxe_img` will not work because jQuery will only find and use the first element.

Second, your first item in your array is not a proper string. This should be throwing javascript errors.

Third, some of your images are `jpeg`, others are `jepg`. They should probably all be `jpeg`.

Comment: Also please review "How to Ask" and "MVE" in the Help section. Specifically, you need to tell us in what way "it isn't working". If there is an error leave post it. Otherwise compare your result to you desired result, and give an example of what you get vs what you want. That really expedites our ability to contribute to solving your issue. Thanks. Just click the `edit` button to add additional info. That helps us help you.

Answer (score 2):

As Christian Hain pointed out in the comment, `id` are supposed to be unique while you have 6 `img` with the same `id`. You must use classes for these situations.

If you use the string `function(displayImage())` as attribute, your browser will look for a image called exactly `function(displayImage())` and will not evaluate it  as Javascript, because it doesn't understand it is javascript code. You need to use the javascript line for changing them also on the first page load to set the initial values:

```
$(".deluxe_img").attr("src", displayImage());
```

Why do you set the interval everytime that `!usedImages[num]` evaluates to `false`? This will keep generating new interval, so your code will constantly be running and not only once every 5 seconds. You need to handle the case when `!usedImages[num]` evaluates to `false` by looking for a different `num`

```
var imageIndexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
function displayImage() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imageIndexes.length));
    var num = imageIndexes[index]

    var result = imagesArray[num];
    imageIndexes.splice(index, 1)

    if (imageIndexes.length === 0) {
        imageIndexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
    }
    return result
}


function changeImagesSrc() {
    $(".deluxe_img").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('src',displayImage())
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    changeImagesSrc()
    setInterval(function() {
        changeImagesSrc()
    }, 5000);
})
```

Comment: Happy to help :) Can you mark the answer as accepted then, so the question can get "closed"?

Comment: i'm sorry for the confusion but after I wrote thanks it's working there was an issue with the code only showing user_IDS 1-12. Whilst the question mentions an array of user_IDs - it also states that this was for example/illustration purposes only. It just took me a little bit to realise the code was not working exactly as required. and therefore cannot logically accept this as the answer sorry.

Comment: That's not a problem if you don't want to accept the answer but please note that Stack Overflow is a place to find help with your problems, not a place where the people write code for you. Of course it was just an example, I don't have the proper data and I don't have access to the whole project, there is no way I can be able to provide you with a code to just copy and paste without the need for you to at least read and understand it :)